# Setting background image with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

Good Day

I want to dynamically set the background images on a div, inside a li element, so that I do not have to specify each div's background image individually....

My code (JS) however,is not working.
Also see my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RK5B4/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="imageWrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div></div> <span></span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <div></div> <span></span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <div></div> <span></span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <div></div> <span></span>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#imageWrapper ul li div {
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var length = 4; //This is the number of images I have to add
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        $('#imageWrapper ul li div').css('background', 'url(/path/images/' + i '.jpg)');
    }
});
```

Also, this list of images I want to load is pretty big. What is the best way to load so many images and populate them in the DOM without having to write out all the html and css - thats just stupid

Thank you

Comment: Why not just put them in your stylesheet to begin with?

Comment: Agreed. If you want to script the HTML elements so you don't have to write each one, I would recommend PHP.

Comment: the background-images? I have a=many images, and I want to use as little code as possible - there certainly has to be a way to load a lot of images (even if its just background images) without having to write out all of the css/html...

Comment: @kcdwayne - Can't you do it with javascript?

Comment: You can, but since you're talking about a potentially large operation for javascript (which would use resources from the client - very bad for mobile - causes crashes). PHP uses the servers processing power and delivers the content dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this code, but it's not recommended to handle this with JavaScript if you have to touch up that many elements to change their backgrounds.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#imageWrapper ul li').each(function(i){
        $(this)
            .find('div')
            .css('background-image', 'url(/path/images/' + (i+1) + '.jpg)');
    });
});
```

Comment: why not javascript? What about the popularity of Ajax in preloading images/creating image arrays? Does it have to be php/server side?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden Popularity of Ajax doesn't have to do with the image preloading. It has to do with other things. Image preloading is a thing of a past if you ask me. If you mean image lazy(on demand)loading that's another point.

Comment: I see...what do you recommend I do? Write out the html/css? Server side scripting?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden Exactly! It's faster and cache-able, if you use any caching mechanism in your application = less irritations and holdups for the visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the PHP method.

```
<?php 
  echo '<div id="imageWrapper"><ul>';
    $i=4;
      while($i-->0){
       echo '<li class="background-'.$i.'"><div></div><span></span></li>'.PHP_EOL;
      }
  echo '</ul></div>';
?>
```

It prints out 4 `<li>`s with the div and span. You would still have to add background with CSS.

The elements print out `.background-1`, `.background-2`, so you can just make background changes by editing the class quick and easy.